# How to return everything in a paragraph but the first sentence using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have the following paragraph:

```
The red fox. The blue fish. The pink dog.
```

How do I return everything but the first sentence?

```
The blue fish. The pink dog.  // what I'm looking for
```

Since I'm using `^([^.]+(. ))` to grab the first sentence (including period and following whitespace) I was hoping to use it as a way to omit it but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this pattern:

```
^([\w\s]+\.\s)(.+)$
```

Except the first sentence with the dot, we get everything from the following.

```js
var pattern = /^([\w\s]+\.\s)(.+)$/;

var arr = 'The red fox. The blue fish. The pink dog.'.match(pattern);

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[2]);
```

Comment: And if I happen to have a comma in my first sentence, I updated your solution to be `^([\w\s\S]+\.)(.+)$`

Comment: This does not seem to match only the first sentence of each paragraph. Please see [Javascript demo](https://regex101.com/r/uiJ5H5/4/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used `split` and `splice` to solve the same issue. You can check this solution.

```js
const removeFirstSentence = (text) => {
  const lines = text.split('.');
  lines.splice(0, 1);
  return lines.join('.').trim();
}

let lines = "The red fox. The blue fish. The pink dog."
lines = removeFirstSentence(lines);
console.log(lines);
```

Comment: Nice solution. While this does work I'm trying to find the solution using regex.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation :) Though you can give an upvote as appreciation :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume consecutive paragraphs are separated by two or more newlines in a row.

You could use the regular expression

```
^(?<![^\r\n]\r?\n)[A-Z][^.]*\.\s*
```

converting matches (first sentences of paragraphs) to empty strings.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uiJ5H5/3/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^          # match the beginning of a line
(?<!       # begin a negative lookbehind (to ensure the current
           # line is the first line of a paragraph.
  [^\r\n]  # match any char other than \r and \n
  \r?\n    # match \n optionally be preceded by \r 
)          # end negative lookbehind
[A-Z]      # match a capital letter
[^.]*      # match 0+ chars other periods
\.         # match a period
\s*        # match 0+ spaces
```